# All emails blocked via Sendgrid, how to get emails delivered again?

Tags: azure, email, sendgrid, spam

We use Sendgrid in an Azure App-service, but since a week all sent messages are blocked. Spamhaus listed several Sendgrid IP-addresses in their SBL (Spamhaus Block List). Users of Sendgrid can't remove these Spamhaus entries. How to get it fixed?

Answer (score 5):

Noticed the same thing and I've been looking at switching to Mailjet instead of Sendgrid. This article paints a rather bleak view regarding Sendgrid [this article](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2020/08/sendgrid-under-siege-from-hacked-accounts/comment-page-1/).